# Xamarin android - Returning from push notification won't display page content

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Returning from a **push-notification**, my Xamarin android App **won't show the content** of my **Page**.

Reproducing:

1. "Minimizing" the app
2. Click a recieved push notification to open the app

The app starts as expected. However, after starting it's supposed to display my start page (a simple ContentPage with a WebView) - but nothing is shown. Debugging, I can see that my page is loaded (OnAppearing is called). 
Starting the app "minimized" usually works - just not when clicking from a notification!

Code for when the app recieves a notification (please tell me if other code is more relevant!):

```
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.testicon)
   .SetContentTitle("Test")
   .SetContentText(messageBody)
   .SetAutoCancel(true)
   .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
   .SetVisibility(NotificationVisibility.Public)
   .SetPriority((int)Android.App.NotificationPriority.High);

var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

Any help to point me in *any* direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The app starts as expected. However, after starting it's supposed to display my start page (a simple ContentPage with a WebView) - but nothing is shown.

If you need your Forms app to start from the beginning, you need to comment out/remove `intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);`. This flag will restore the existing running app instead of running a new instance of your app.

Comment: Did not resolve my issue unfortunately, but thank you for the lead!

Comment: Could you share a basic sample that can reproduce the issue? Not reproducable by my side.

Comment: Might it be that my MainActivity LaunchMode is set to Multiple? Noticed that if I changed it to SingleTask it works with your solution.